# CPU usage of worker processes on a multicore server

Tags: c#, .net, multicore, cpu-usage, worker

### The setup

We've written a Windows service, which fires off separate worker processes to perform various CPU-intensive tasks. The server and workers communicate via IPC named pipes.

At present, we create the workers via a simple `Process.Start()` call.

When we run up a number of workers on a fairly low-spec'd **dual core** server VM, Task Manager tells us that each worker uses approximately 2 - 3% CPU.

However (this is thing that's confusing us), when we perform the same test on a very powerful **eight-core** server, we still see each worker process using 2 - 3% CPU. Now, because there is more CPU 'power' available, I would expect to see each worker using a much smaller percentage of CPU.

This also means that on the low-powered server we hit 100% CPU after 30ish worker processes are created. But on the high-powered CPU, we hit the same limit after the same number of workers. We would expect to be able to run far more workers.

### The issue

So, I have a couple of questions:

- Are we misunderstanding the values that Task Manager is telling us? The CPU % value is the amount of CPU time consumed across all cores? If so, why is it the same on vastly different hardware?
- Should we be doing something special / different to properly distribute our worker processes across multiple cores? At the moment, the processes have the default processor affinity (so they are able to run on any core).

Any help, advice, links, would be greatly appreciated.

---

Some extra info for people who have left comments:

I didn't mention it initially as I didn't necessarily want to add extra complexity to my question, but our worker processes are doing video transcoding of live video streams. As such, no worker ever 'completes' its task - it simply works for as long as a client is connected.

Essentially:

- A client connects to the server
- The server fires off a worker process which connects to a remote video stream
- When video is received from said video stream, the worker transcodes it and sends the transcoded video back to the client.

Not sure if this helps with any other suggestions? Thanks for all the comments so far.

Comment: are your tasks CPU bound? I would expect a CPU bound task to consume most of 1 core for as long as the task takes. i.e. around 50% and 12.5% respectively.

Comment: Is the overall throughput different on the two systems?  (Not the apparent CPU usage, but the total amount of work done in a given wall clock time)

Comment: to paraphrase @Reed Copsey, does the big box finish faster?

Comment: Another nice think to ask is.. did you try it with 30 workers?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are the speeds/architectures of the CPUs different?  If the dual-core machine is significantly faster, has lower-latency memory access, has bigger caches, etc, then it is quite possible that it is actually as performant as the 8-core machine.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the processes are using 2-3% of the CPU suggests that your process is not CPU bound, but rather is likely to be IO bound or have some other limitation.

The IO on the 2 core server **VM** is probably quite a bit slower than your 8 core server, which, in turn, throttles the behavior there.  This may be why the apparent CPU usage is the same, though I would suspect that the full server likely finishes the task sooner overall.

Comment: You make a very good point about CPU vs IO bound. Even if this is the case, would you not still expect the CPU usage to be lower on the system with more cores? (because it's a percentage spread over a large number of cores)

Comment: @JamesFrost Not necessarily - the system with more cores could have faster IO, which in turn "reduces the IO throttling" effect on the CPU.  If the IO is faster on that system (since it's not a VM), it could compensate for the extra cores.  This was why I asked about the overall throughput...